# Log XML request and response (from SoapCore.SoapEndpointMiddleware)

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, soap, windows-update

I'm using the [Upsync](https://github.com/microsoft/update-server-server-sync/tree/master/src/tools/upsync) utility to manually provide updates to Windows Update Agent (WUA) and I need to log and view the XML request and response, specifically the response. I can see that the logger is configured [here](https://github.com/microsoft/update-server-server-sync/blob/51999ec00741ef4c8948d9b743588597245a9958/src/tools/upsync/UpdateServer.cs#L39):

```cs
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseUrls($"http://{bindEndpoint}:{bindPort}")
.UseStartup<UpdateServerStartup>()
.UseKestrel()
.ConfigureKestrel((context, opts) => { })
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{
    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    logging.AddConsole();
    logging.AddDebug();
    logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
})
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    var configDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "metadata-path", metadataPath },
        { "content-path", contentPath },
        { "service-config-json", serviceConfigurationJson },
        { "content-http-root", $"http://{bindEndpoint}:{bindPort}/microsoftupdate/content" },
    };

    config.AddInMemoryCollection(configDictionary);
})
.Build();
```

And this is the output when I run the code and check for updates:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[63]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\amir\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\WSUS\update-server-server-sync-3.0\out\upsync\Debug\net6.0\
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8530
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.230.13:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx text/xml;+charset=utf-8 234
info: SoapCore.SoapEndpointMiddleware[0]
      Request for operation IClientSyncWebService.GetConfig received
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.230.13:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx text/xml;+charset=utf-8 234 - 200 6492 text/xml;+charset=utf-8 934.2433ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.230.13:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx text/xml;+charset=utf-8 837
info: SoapCore.SoapEndpointMiddleware[0]
      Request for operation IClientSyncWebService.GetConfig2 received
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.230.13:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx text/xml;+charset=utf-8 837 - 200 6496 text/xml;+charset=utf-8 305.0248ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.230.13:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx text/xml;+charset=utf-8 727
info: SoapCore.SoapEndpointMiddleware[0]
      Request for operation IClientSyncWebService.GetCookie received
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.230.13:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx text/xml;+charset=utf-8 727 - 200 508 text/xml;+charset=utf-8 646.2828ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.230.13:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx text/xml;+charset=utf-8 553
info: SoapCore.SoapEndpointMiddleware[0]
      Request for operation IClientSyncWebService.SyncUpdates received
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.230.13:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx text/xml;+charset=utf-8 553 - 200 10212 text/xml;+charset=utf-8 482.5846ms
```

We can see that the WUA requests for multiple operations (GetConfig, GetConfig2, GetCookie, SyncUpdates) and for each, an XML response is given. I'm trying to view that XML response.

I tried setting the log level to `Trace` so that it logs everything, with

```cs
logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
```

But this doesn't print out the XML that is sent in response.

How can I print the XML results?

I searched for [c# webhostbuilder soapcore logging](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+webhostbuilder+soapcore+logging), but only [this question with no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71038572/programatically-add-remove-soap-core-endpoints-in-kestrel) came up.

Comment: Edit the file UpdateServer.cs and add : logging.getLogger('spyne.protocol.xml').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  In c# you need to replace the single quotes with double quotes and add semicolon to the end.

Comment: @jdweng logging doesn't have a `getLogger` method in C#. That code was an example in Python.

Comment: It is the same library and does have the option. You simply have to modify the  UpdateServer.cs file.  The library doesn't change just because you call it from c# instead of Python.

Comment: @jdweng It does say `'ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'getLogger'`. And I'm not using `Spyne` here, that's just an example to show how I could get a logger in Python to log the XML.

Comment: You just answered your own question.  You are using two different libraries.  If you want the XML results you either have to use Spyne, or write a method for Upsync that displays the XML results.  If the libraries are calling the same server than you simply add the parameter to the request in c# like in Python and Spyne.

Comment: @jdweng You're right, perhaps I should delete the Spyne example. I'm looking for a method in Upsync that displays the XML, but can't find one.

Comment: Upsync is calling "http://{bindEndpoint}:{bindPort}/microsoftupdate/content".  If Spyne also calling same URL than you should be able to change request to return XML.  You would then need to take the XML response in Upsync and process similar to Spyne.

Comment: @jdweng Nice. I think I can do that.